# How to extract ID tags from MP3 files in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, mp3, tags

Please advise some way to extract MP3 attributes using simple API.
Is there any other libraries other than [ID3.framework](http://drewfamily.homemail.com.au/Cocoa_-_ID3Tag_framework.html)? I found that it is quite out-dated and has memory leaks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is acceptable for you to use QTKit then check out QTMovie_Metadata.h and QTMovie_Metadata.m that are part of the qtplay project on Google Code http://code.google.com/p/qtplay/

The specific files are here:

http://code.google.com/p/qtplay/source/browse/trunk/Source/Categories%20and%20Wrappers/QTMovie_Metadata.h

http://code.google.com/p/qtplay/source/browse/trunk/Source/Categories%20and%20Wrappers/QTMovie_Metadata.m