# getting the information of the audio file like author, title, album, year, etc. 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading MP3 information using objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239460/reading-mp3-information-using-objective-c)

for an mp3 file how i can read last 128 bytes of mp3 file

Comment: The file format for an MP3 file is here: http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html