# Is there a way to extract embedded image data from an mp3 in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, mp3

I understand that mp3s sometimes contain album artwork (in my case, I'm working with podcast files). Is there a way in iOS to extract the image data from an mp3 file?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239460/reading-mp3-information-using-objective-c

Answer (score 9):

MP3s, including podcasts, do often have embedded metadata, including artwork. The easiest way to get the embedded metadata (for MP3s not in the iTunes library) is through the `AVAsset` class. If you are trying to get metadata over a network use the `AVURLAsset` instead, but accessing the metadata is the same with either.

`AVAsset` has an `NSArray` property named `commonMetadata` which contains instances of the class `AVMetadataItem`. You can iterate over this array to find the element with the `commonKey` of(usually) "`artwork`" The `value` property of this `AVMetadataItem` should be an `NSDictionary` of data about the artwork. Within this dictionary you will find the key "`data`" which should contain data you can use to construct a `UIImage`. This is quite nested and this description is admittedly confusing. So here is a code example.

```
NSURL *url = <# url of resource here #>;
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
for (AVMetadataItem *metadataItem in asset.commonMetadata) {
    if ([metadataItem.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){
        NSDictionary *imageDataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)metadataItem.value;
        NSData *imageData = [imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
         // Display this image on my UIImageView property imageView
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }
}
```

Again this is a very simple example of how to load from a local resource; If you are loading this over a network you should use an `AVURLAsset`. Also be careful of the blocking nature of this call.

Comment: +1 NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];  where str is the path of file ..i stuck because i m using [NSURL URLWithString:str]..I posted..maybe help others:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's sample [AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html) project and you'll see how they get the album artwork via MPMediaItem & [MPMediaItemArtwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) objects.

Comment: Thanks Michael but correct me if I'm wrong, my understanding is that MPMediaItems only refer to items in the user's iPod library. I am parsing a podcast's rss feed and streaming audio for a podcast the user has not subscribed to in iTunes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, for some reason I thought the podcast was already in your iTunes library.  Let me go back to the drawing board.  Right now, I can't imagine that artwork is somehow embedded in a .mp3 file.  Maybe in the .m3u playlist or in the RSS feed, but in a .mp3 file?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)getMP3Pic:(NSURL *)url
{
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    for (AVMetadataItem *metadataItem in asset.commonMetadata) {
       if ([metadataItem.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){
            return [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)metadataItem.value];
       }
    }
}
```