# How to set image in UIImageView from image of audio file in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview, avaudioplayer

I want to make basic Audio Player app by programatically.
If every Audio file contain image then I want that in UIImageView automatically set image from audio file.
If any file doesn't contain any image file then it should be set default image.

Like i shown below:

[image]

Comment: This is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814248/is-there-a-way-to-extract-embedded-image-data-from-an-mp3-in-ios?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

check how you are taking those images. 
-case its Networking, use SDWebImage, take a look here:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

-case those images are saved in a core data (example) make a search in your data, if exists,
pick that data and convert it to an image

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imagewithData:dataImage];
```

remember you need to have a database image online or offline. Then just make a search, case exists, put the image, case not, default image.

Comment: Thank you very much [Juan Munhoes Junior](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1735014/juan-munhoes-junior)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you need can be found in [Apple's Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html) as referenced in the question that overbombing referenced.  They make it easy for you:

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];

// Assume that there is no artwork for the media item.
UIImage *artworkImage = noArtworkImage;

// Get the artwork from the current media item, if it has artwork.
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

// Obtain a UIImage object from the MPMediaItemArtwork object
if (artwork) {
    artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (30, 30)];
}
```

I would advise reading through [Apple's Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html) anyway it seems you are doing pretty much exactly what they did.