# iOS: Displaying currently played track info in LockScreen?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

As of iOS 5 we have access to `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` to display info in the lockscreen and in the multimedia controls on the multitasking bar. I have an app that plays **local** audio files. I want to display info like the artist's name, the album and the artwork on the lockscreen with `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, but the only way to do this (As far as I know) is to   use `MPMusicPlayerController` and get `nowPlayingItem`... The problem is that `MPMusicPlayerController` is used to play iPod Music only, and not locally stored files. Is there a way around this in iOS 5?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create your own NSDictionary and supply that to the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, ..., nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Album", @"Artist", ..., nil];
NSDictionary *mediaInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:mediaInfo];
```

Comment: But how do I get the album name of a locally stored track? Or the artwork?

Comment: You will need to read the ID3 tags of the locally stored file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239460/reading-mp3-information-using-objective-c

Comment: You also need to specify that you app receives remote control events:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`

Comment: Don't forget to `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`