# How to display (the official way) custom art in the lock screen while app is running

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I've heard folks say that Apple will not allow doing things like this: [How to set lock screen , wallpaper and Ringtone programmatically in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476777/how-to-set-lock-screen-wallpaper-and-ringtone-programmatically-in-iphone/4476831#4476831)

I wonder however, if there is an official way of doing this. If not, or how are music apps like Songza displaying the playing artwork in the lock screen?

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: [iOS: Displaying currently played track info in LockScreen?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675154/ios-displaying-currently-played-track-info-in-lockscreen