# Getting info about an mp3 file in ios 5

Tags: audio, ios5

How do I get the info about a mp3 file? I mean, like, the tags and the artwork? Any one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, but here goes:
Assuming you mean any kind of audio file that resides in the iPod library, this information is contained in an MPMediaItem instance. These objects can be obtained in various ways, for example by using the MPMediaPickerController. The MPMediaItem is contained in the Media Player framework.

Reference here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Small Example:

```
NSString *songTitle = [MPMediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Now, if you're actually talking about an mp3 file residing in your App's sandbox, the answer you're looking for is located in this thread: [Reading MP3 information using objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239460/reading-mp3-information-using-objective-c)